# C# - Custom control with panel on it, how do I make the IDE add items to the panel?

Tags: c#, custom-controls, panel

I have a custom control which contains a panel, of which I want to be able to drop controls on in the VS IDE and have those controls actually be a child of the panel (which is a child of my custom control) and not have them added to the form my custom control is on.

Basically what happens when you drop controls on a panel not contained in a custom control.

I've tried to google it, but can't seem to come up with any good results, any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're talking about WinForms I think you'll get what you want if you change your custom control to inherit from [ContainerControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.aspx) rather than `UserControl`.

If it's WebForms it might be worth looking at [ContainerControlDesigner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.design.containercontroldesigner.aspx), but I don't know much about that.

Comment: Is there anyway to replicate the Load event for a ContainerControl?

Comment: @Blam: Not sure which Event would be best for that, I'd suggest trying `Layout`, `GotFocus`, `Enter` or `VisibleChanged` since they all sound like they might be useful. Or otherwise you could just have an Initialize method that gets called in the Form's `Load` event.